# drf nested routers - route subroutine for endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I have a old endpoint with a URL like this:

```
url(r'^vehicles/([^/]{1,50})/trips/data/?$', 'vehicle_trip_data'),
```

which was mapped to my function based view.

I am now refactoring the works to work with drf-nested-routers.
What I know is, that I can route to custom methods. Like when I have the former Endpoint `url(r'^vehicles/([^/]{1,50})/trips/?$', 'vehicle_trips_view')` I am just adding a method `trips` like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, VehiclePermissions])
def trips(self, request, pk=None):
```

I obviously can't just name the method trips/data.
So is there a way how I can make a detailed route for the first example!?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `trips/data` in `url_path` parameter.

```
@detail_route(methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, VehiclePermissions], url_path='trips/data')
def trips(self, request, pk=None):
```